# Blazor Navigation manager to specified URI (google.com)

Tags: navigation, blazor, blazor-server-side, navigatetourl

i have a question about how to redirect page to certain page like google.com

I've tried with below but it's not working...

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

void()
{
 NavigationManager.NavigateTo("google.com");
}
```

but it moved to the link with ultimate uri.
like localhost:3030/google.com

how could i move to a page like google.com in Blazor?

Answer (score 1):

While `void()` isn't valid C# I think we can guess what you are trying.

Just `"google.com"` will be seen as a local (relative) URI, that won't work.

Use:

```cs
//NavigationManager.NavigateTo("google.com");
  NavigationManager.NavigateTo("https://google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visit Google page with click of button, you can do it like this

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">Google</button>
```